# Loop through object for matching usernames, if found add a 1

Tags: javascript, json, string, loops

Checking for matching usernames...

I'm looping through a json object datam. I am checking to see if string variable un doesn't already exist in json object id un. If it does add a 1 to string variable un.

```
var un = "John"

for (var i=0;i<datam.length;i++){
    if(datam[i].un == un){
        un = un+1 //I know this is wrong what's the correct way? :)
        alert(un) //John1 if John1 exist John2 etc..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could make all your user names unique.

```
var datam = [
        { un: 'John' },
        { un: 'John' },
        { un: 'John' },
        { un: 'Foo' }
    ],
    unCount = {};

datam.forEach(function (user, i) {
    var un = user.un;

    if (unCount[un]) user.un += unCount[un]++;
    else unCount[un] = 1;
});

datam[0].un; // John
datam[1].un; // John1
```

Comment: sql results get stored in datam. So I can't go back and correct all the duplicating names plus I shouldn't have to with the solution I'm after making sure each username is already unique. I just need it to check that the new user isn't going to have the same one as an already existing user...

Comment: @Quaking-Mess I would rather inform the user that his name has been taken and allow him to try a new one rather than forcing one on him, such as adding a number at the end.

Comment: good idea, I know I wasn't entirely descriptive I just wanted to get straight to the code. But the account will be made by an admin who'll then inform the user of their username and password... But I think I will go with this suggestion to lessen any confusion for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
var j = 0
var testname = un

    for (var i=0;i<datam.length;i++){

         if(datam[i].un == testname){
            j++
            testname = un+j.toString();
            i = 0 //restart the loop and see if John(1,2,3..) is in datam.un
            }

        }
    alert(testname)
```